# Website menu is hidden behind page - Z-index

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I have an issue with a site i'm working on in that the menu displays only the first child items on the homepage (overlayed on top of a metaslider), but the menu displays correctly on the remaining pages. I have tried manipulating the z-index of the menu, the slider and the page content to no avail.

What I have figured out is when the site content contain div is given a z-index of 100 (as it is now):

```
.site-content-contain {
    z-index: 100!important;
}
```

the site content shows but the menu has an issue.
As soon as It's value is 99 or less, I can access the menu properly but then the site container has issues.

Other relevant information is that the theme being used is a customized child of TwentySeventeen.

Here is the link:
https://www.enitan.co.uk/home/

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I make your menu works if you remove the `z-index` from both your header (`.site-header`) and your site container (`.site-content-contain`) :

[image]

But it is not really readable (white/white), maybe you could add a border or a box-shadow

Comment: not sure why you were downvoted but this fixed my issue, I had to set the z-index to auto to pick the default (which I believe is 3)

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
#masthead {
    z-index: 999;
    background-color: red !important; /*You need to use gradient color here */
}
```

Comment: If you put this css property your issue will be solve just check it you need to add fades transparent color their....